# Vega-lite: Text annotations using layer with selection

Tags: kibana, vega-lite, vega

I am a beginner with Vega-Lite and I tried to create a dropdown using column-names using selection and fold. I am trying to add annotations using layers but I cant seem to manage it to work with the drop down I have. It shows only one text value in the middle of the chart. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 300,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "resize": true, "contains": "padding"},  "data": {
     "values": [
            {

          "country" : "Egypt",
          "Rating" : 9.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "General Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Coffee"

      },
      {
          "country" : "Japan",
          "Rating" : 8.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "General Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Digital"

      },
      {

          "country" : "Greece",
          "Rating" : 4.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Medicine"

      },
      {

          "country" : "France",
          "Rating" : 8.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Cups"

      },
      {

          "country" : "Japan",
          "Rating" : 7.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "JAPAN"

      },
      {
          "country" : "Japan",
          "Rating" : 10.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Pc"

      },
      {
          "country" : "Japan",
          "Rating" : 8.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Books"

      },
      {

          "country" : "Denmark",
          "Rating" : 3.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "Kalem"

      },
      {
          "country" : "Netherlands",
          "Rating" : 6.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
          "dv_survey" : "General Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "HR"

      },
      {

          "country" : "Turkiye",
          "Rating" : 5.0,
          "taken_on" : "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
               "dv_survey" : "Business Application Xperience Survey",
          "department_displayvalue" : "TURKEY"

      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"filter": {"field": "dv_survey", "equal": "Business Application Xperience Survey"}},
     {"calculate": "datum.department_displayvalue", "as": "department"},

    {
      "fold": ["department", "country"],
      "as": ["Choice", "val"]
    },
    {"filter": {"selection": "kpi"}}
  ],

  "layer": [
    {
  "selection": {
    "kpi": {
      "type": "single",
      "init": {"Choice": "country"},
      "bind": {
        "Choice": {
          "name": "Ratings Per",
          "input": "select",
          "options": [
            "department",
            "country"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "point": true, "color": "#FFC94E", "height": 15},
  "encoding": {
    "tooltip": {
          "field": "Rating",
          "aggregate": "average",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Rating",
          "format": ".1f"
        },
    "x": {
      "field": "Rating",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "average",
      "axis": null
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "val",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelSeparation": 1, "labelPadding": 4, "title": null}
    }
      }
    },

    {
    "mark": {"type": "text","align": "left","baseline": "middle"},

      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "Rating", "type": "quantitative"},"tooltip": {
          "field": "Rating",
          "aggregate": "average",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Rating",
          "format": ".1f"
        }}

    }

    ]
}
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cR2S.png)

[My code in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBsABh1L4NMljQBmPUpxI1amrLJoArEqQNMbCDQBecNKEwAnji+6ABmdIogAE5wnj5omFEMcEpQcphIdhBoIFY2dg4AvkpqSBl+IMRIgsnZqADaoGkMsokBOQCiZEGYkQBKZQVoAJxKGQDWcLIA+nI5AEw68wCM-Dpaa8MABMs6qHqojgDskWrE0xAMUaTt6ADiU3BR1VsAgjg4wlCDclsAGsEojQplA4FsAMpXG6nOBWKKYBBTTDTWwQT5IAJVGohEAAYTYoVCcF8xSabBabRyACkkFZ5EoBpghqgABxjJCTGZzdCLFZrDY6ba7fZ7Y6nc6Xa5wW4gB6yJ4vd6fGjfJm-AFPYGyUEQqHSmFwhFIlE0NGCDFY5I5AAiRjo1RApJAzVaURldxicFB-UG9jQYnZnNm8h5S1W602Oz2BzFJQleplACEGJ55RAIG8Pl8frJ-oCtTrIVL2iVYUh4YjWiazRbqlb0ABZOC2KB2EkKMkUt05ABiz21vgZvocrMDU2DCzD-MjwpjJzjFwTOWTqdiGaV2bVuY1QJBYKL0NLhsryNR6MxdZxuIYeEdHed5NdMppdJ9TL9qCOY65IZAvPDApCtGorziAZyLsWy4pm26aZsqqrsNu+Z7rqkFHuWRpVme5oXti1KvAACq8AByd6dk+1K0kg9IgIyzK7N+E6hnyEaClGIqHKB4GStC6ArjB65ZiqOZ5pqKEHvq6EVsa2G1nh6AEVAZEPl2z5UTRdEfmyIATOO3J-lOrFARxsZgfGkF8dBaaCfBIk7gW+5LlJmGnqa56WjiiZsGw4zZE6LqUug1pTMgUTjG+zKmIx+n-tObGziB4oQbxID8dZcGbohom7gOqGHmBZbSVhbk4R5OQANLVIgykBd26DEXA9BPOashqNkQ7viOWjRb+sVGexc5JTx+r3I8zyCBlwlbtlDl5ZJBXHjJJVyfWIAABJ9DVj6BSAAAqVzjDQASDrRw5OD1k4sYBA2JQuw1JlZa6TQh6rIblEklgtGEntW7mXjku0AKp9OVHQAJqOgAusUOn9hAoRsFECBoI0IDhIImBPBU4RwIIag5NxTkgHAACODAOpZq6wRuU1ZfZ4lLoU-nVFADDmpjBNlAwCCUGohUub9pX-S4dRfUVvROgjeMo2LLmRLV7SQyLMu4jAbAqidWIgND97o5jUQVBAuNeluOTjDgNCOoUSsgDhWMNKARuCCbiEVObluoP4QQ4qmZDO5EdgRJ7eJqxrOQK3eIBMHY+PB6r6vesHshIIiOSaWQGYEVjSh2Dgbg5E7JuRGwOBbnU9Syye8vbd20NMzDoXhcHgTBDkTDlpEODq60CRJCkD6CIjOQAMQ9j2uLDGIHSRIYxi9KgyyODDIJsLYH7+N5GM0Dg2PAtL6Dp5ESBkGQMQUBz6BIKQzxkCdLc4mT1FMhkTKkJEz-+wfZ1KAjSNlDklBlihEjgAD13rjWOp1Orv29jkR+rR7SvxOsfU+fAL4gCvgqW+R8QGmjQLINmggYa3FADjfelQHRjFgegWQbAEB2EoRg3BdRQDmiYLjcEhUcxoGWEoNhuMCLWDXiOAMOk6CfwIYIIh9d7yNwqPfHImMQG9BcMIMgv5nahBUVHJATs2w5HoTYf2y9tSr2ZP4OAyjwHkMPlQ1u6B4HP0GG-GG7g2Bbx3sHMhkDbEYJPmfMoOJME3zvtQkAjjEE0DfmMcROJfG-2QPPEAgDgH12hkAA)

Answer (score 3):

As the understanding goes, you want to show the text next to bar charts but currently you are getting one text in the center which if you notice is getting overlapped or superimpose on top of each other. There is no x or y axis provided in your text layer. I have created a common x and y encoding outside of layers using your bar chart layer and added aggregation to your text. Below is the config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgBsABh1L4NMljQBmPUpxI1amrLJoArEqQNMbCDQBecNKEwAnji+6ABmdIogAE5wnj5omFEMcEpQcphIdhBoIFY2dg4AvkpqSBl+IMRIgsnZqADaoGkMsokBOQCiZEGYkQBKZQVoAJxKGQDWcLIA+nI5AEw68wCM-Dpaa8MABMs6qHqojgDskWrE0xAMUaTt6ADiU3BR1VsAgjg4wlCDclsAGsEojQplA4FsAMpXG6nOBWKKYBBTTDTWwQT5IAJVGohEAAYTYoVCcF8xSabBabRyACkkFZ5EoBpghqgABxjJCTGZzdCLFZrDY6ba7fZ7Y6nc6Xa5wW4gB6yJ4vd6fGjfJm-AFPYGyUEQqHSmFwhFIlE0NGCDFY5I5AAiRjo1RApJAzVaURldxicFB-UG9jQYnZnNm8h5S1W602Oz2BzFJQleplACEGJ55RAIG8Pl8frJ-oCtTrIVL2iVYUh4YjWiazRbqlb0ABZOC2KB2EkKMkUt05ABiz21vgZvocrMDU2DCzD-MjwpjJzjFwTOWTqdiGaV2bVuY1QJBYKL0NLhsryNR6MxdZxuIYeEdHed5NdMppdJ9TL9qCOY65IZAvPDApCtGorziAZyLsWy4pm26aZsqqrsNu+Z7rqkFHuWRpVme5oXti1KvAACq8AByd6dk+1K0kg9IgIyzK7N+E6hnyEaClGIqHKB4GStC6ArjB65ZiqOZ5pqKEHvq6EVsa2G1nh6AEVAZEPl2z5UTRdEfmyIATOO3J-lOrFARxsZgfGkF8dBaaCfBIk7gW+5LlJmGnqa56WjiiZsGw4zZE6LqUug1pTMgUTjG+zKmIx+n-tObGziB4oQbxID8dZcGbohom7gOqGHmBZbSVhbk4R5OQANLVIgykBd26DEXA9BPOashqNkQ7viOWjRb+sVGexc5JTx+r3I8zyCBlwlbtlDl5ZJBXHjJJVyfWIAABJ9DVj6BSAAAqVzjDQASDrRw5OD1k4sYBA2JQuw1JlZa6TQh6rIblEklgtGEntW7mXjku0AKp9OVHQAJqOgAusUOn9hAoRsFECBoI0IDhIImBPBU4RwIIag5NxTkgHAACODAOpZq6wRuU1ZfZ4lLoU-nVFADDmpjBNlAwCCUGohUub9pX-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-OAj-bCJoMHGG7g2B0IYbPbOzCnEuHYa4rhHjeGBJyH7IRgdQmiN7jieJaNEY+LkQopR0MgA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 300,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit", "resize": true, "contains": "padding"},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "country": "Egypt",
        "Rating": 9,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Coffee"
      },
      {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Rating": 8,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Digital"
      },
      {
        "country": "Greece",
        "Rating": 4,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Medicine"
      },
      {
        "country": "France",
        "Rating": 8,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Cups"
      },
      {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Rating": 7,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "JAPAN"
      },
      {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Rating": 10,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Pc"
      },
      {
        "country": "Japan",
        "Rating": 8,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Books"
      },
      {
        "country": "Denmark",
        "Rating": 3,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "Kalem"
      },
      {
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "Rating": 6,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "General Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "HR"
      },
      {
        "country": "Turkiye",
        "Rating": 5,
        "taken_on": "2021-06-09 10:00:57",
        "dv_survey": "Business Application Xperience Survey",
        "department_displayvalue": "TURKEY"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": {
        "field": "dv_survey",
        "equal": "Business Application Xperience Survey"
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.department_displayvalue", "as": "department"},
    {"fold": ["department", "country"], "as": ["Choice", "val"]},
    {"filter": {"selection": "kpi"}}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Rating",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "aggregate": "average",
      "axis": null
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "val",
      "type": "nominal",
      "axis": {"labelSeparation": 1, "labelPadding": 4, "title": null}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "selection": {
        "kpi": {
          "type": "single",
          "init": {"Choice": "country"},
          "bind": {
            "Choice": {
              "name": "Ratings Per",
              "input": "select",
              "options": ["department", "country"]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "point": true, "color": "#FFC94E", "height": 15},
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": {
          "field": "Rating",
          "aggregate": "average",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Rating",
          "format": ".1f"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left", "baseline": "middle"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "Rating",
          "aggregate": "average",
          "format": ".1f",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "field": "Rating",
          "aggregate": "average",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Rating",
          "format": ".1f"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!!